# How to set the right access right for local (apache) server?

Tags: apache, joomla

I'm running an apache server on my laptop (macbook pro osx 10.9.2) for web development purposes. When I installed a Joomla example web application and I try some feature (like changing the fontsettings via joomla administrator) I get numerous error messages indicating it can't write to some subfolder(s). When I manually change the rights for 'everyone' to 'read & write' for the related subfolder with the mac file manager the problem is solved. But I don't think that is the proper solution (everybody can access) and elegant solution (to avoid error messages I would have do that for all subfolders).

How to set the access rights in the proper way? e.g. to which entity should I assign what kind of access rights (as you can see I'm not really familiar with these kind of security issues). If I would use the mac terminal application, what would be the right command?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there fellow mac user (':

Open up the terminal and have a look at the chmod command.

With the chmod command you can change permissions of folders and subfolders.

Have a look at [Chmod tutorial](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchmod.htm)

For example:

```
chmod -R ugo
u=permission for user that owns the file
g=permission for groups that own the file
o=permissions for others
4=read
2=write
1=execute

u=4 -> owner can read but cannot write or execute
u=4 & g=3 -> owner can read | groups that own the file can write and execute but not read from it


// This wil give all users read and write permissions.
chmod -R 666 joomla/
```

Comment: thnx. But is 777 wise from a security perspective?

Comment: No it is not :P
It was just for example purposes.
In ideal circumstances you should determine what folders should have those write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the built-in Apache that ships with Mac OS X you will have a conflict between the default user Apache runs as and the ownership of the files. Either Apache can access them or you can read & write them but not both at the same time.

For example if I issue an `ls -al` in terminal after `cd`ing to my home directory I can see the `~/Sites` directory has these permissions and ownership:

```
drwxr-xr-x+  18 cppl   staff    612  6 Apr 09:32 Sites
```

By default though Apache runs as `_www` in the `_www` group.

So, you either need to add your user to the `_www` group or run Apache as your user.

If you add yourself to the `_www` group you will still to fiddle with the file & directory permissions.

If you change the `httpd.conf` so that Apache runs as your user you will need to find and change this section:

```
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User _www
Group _www
```

Specifically you'll want to set the `User` line to your short username e.g. for me that's `cppl` and generally you'll want to set the group to `staff`, the default for users I guess on Mac OS X. e.g.

```
User cppl
Group staff
```

Of course if you do this, you should probably limit access to Apache to the `localhost` or your private network (excluding routers) via the firewall.

Comment: Hi cppl, thnx (sorry for late response, I was away for a while). When I follow your instructions and change the httpd the apache server does not work (not found by webbrowser) anymore (?). With respect to your firstion option: how to fiffle precisely with the file and dir permissions?